# "Project refresh failed error" while opening a SBT Project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5 on MAC OS High Sierra 10.13.1

Below is the Error log:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:  
...
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:107)
[error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:101)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:57)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:34)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:113)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:76)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[info] shutting down server
```

Comment: Does the sbt project work outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: Yes SBT console works outside of IntelliJ. Also i was able to resolve the issue with Scala console in IntelliJ. It seems Working directory was incorrectly set. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: @Ish What's the solution you implement for this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In SBT Settings (open SBT tab on the right-hand-side, click the gear icon), checking [X] "Use SBT shell for build and import" did the trick.